# Spring Boot application can't write to Heroku's file-system

Tags: hibernate, jpa, heroku, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I have a Spring Boot app running on Heroku. After implementing "Hibernate Search" and upload updated version it's not running anymore. The only dependencies I've added is `hibernate-search-orm` and `hibernate-core`.

Locally it works like a charm. Can't get my brain around this. I will be glad to provide more info if needed.

These are the Heroku logs:

```
2017-09-02T23:31:51.770595+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:51.770  INFO 4 --- [   main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e9b0447] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-09-02T23:31:51.790404+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:51.790  INFO 4 --- [   main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-09-02T23:31:52.411449+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:52.411  INFO 4 --- [   main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 29544 (http)
2017-09-02T23:31:52.435728+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:52.435  INFO 4 --- [   main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-09-02T23:31:52.437947+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:52.437  INFO 4 --- [   main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-09-02T23:31:52.602772+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:52.602  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-09-02T23:31:52.602960+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:52.602  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3620 ms
2017-09-02T23:31:53.501020+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:53.500  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-02T23:31:53.501744+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:53.501  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-02T23:31:53.501852+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:53.501  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-02T23:31:53.502010+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:53.501  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-02T23:31:53.504328+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:53.504  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-09-02T23:31:53.504694+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:53.504  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'multipartFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-02T23:31:53.504911+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:53.504  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-09-02T23:31:55.548334+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:55.548  INFO 4 --- [   main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-09-02T23:31:55.545409+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:55.545  INFO 4 --- [   main] org.hibernate.Version: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
2017-09-02T23:31:55.382479+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:55.379  INFO 4 --- [   main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
2017-09-02T23:31:55.350043+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:55.349  INFO 4 --- [   main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-09-02T23:31:55.645262+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:55.644  INFO 4 --- [   main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-09-02T23:31:56.118259+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:56.118  INFO 4 --- [   main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2017-09-02T23:31:56.428237+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:56.427  INFO 4 --- [   main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-09-02T23:31:56.434602+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:56.434  INFO 4 --- [   main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@522a32b1
2017-09-02T23:31:56.967706+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:56.967  INFO 4 --- [   main] org.hibernate.search.engine.Version  : HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.7.1.Final
2017-09-02T23:31:57.480156+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:57.479  INFO 4 --- [   main] o.h.s.s.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper : HSEARCH000041: Index directory not found, creating: '/var/lucene/indexes'
2017-09-02T23:31:57.496532+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:57.496  WARN 4 --- [   main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-09-02T23:31:57.503029+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:57.502  INFO 4 --- [   main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.527816+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02T23:31:57.527817+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539906+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02T23:31:57.539904+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-09-02 23:31:57.538 ERROR 4 --- [   main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication   : Application startup failed
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539908+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539922+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539923+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539924+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539925+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539926+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539926+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539928+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539929+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539930+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539930+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539931+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539932+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539933+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539933+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539934+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539935+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539935+00:00 app[web.1]:at babstr.Application.main(Application.java:21) [classes!/:na]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539937+00:00 app[web.1]:at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539937+00:00 app[web.1]:at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539938+00:00 app[web.1]:at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539939+00:00 app[web.1]:at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539940+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [babstr_java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539940+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [babstr_java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539941+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [babstr_java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539941+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [babstr_java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539942+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539946+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539947+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539949+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539948+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539949+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539950+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539951+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539951+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539952+00:00 app[web.1]:... 24 common frames omitted
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539953+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager named 'babstr.model.Entry'
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539954+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:291) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539955+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:513) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539955+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:544) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539956+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:100) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539957+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:369) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539958+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:202) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539958+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:120) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539959+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539960+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539960+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:366) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539961+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539961+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539962+00:00 app[web.1]:... 30 common frames omitted
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539962+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000252: Unable to initialize directory provider org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider for index babstr.model.Entry
2017-09-02T23:31:57.539963+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:67) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542103+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.create(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:52) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542105+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:219) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542105+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:82) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542106+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:287) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542106+00:00 app[web.1]:... 41 common frames omitted
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542107+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: /var/lucene/indexes for index babstr.model.Entry
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542107+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:155) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542108+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.DirectoryHelper.getVerifiedIndexPath(DirectoryHelper.java:88) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542108+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.DirectoryHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryHelper.java:104) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542109+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:49) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542109+00:00 app[web.1]:at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:64) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.7.1.Final.jar!/:5.7.1.Final]
2017-09-02T23:31:57.542110+00:00 app[web.1]:... 45 common frames omitted
2017-09-02T23:31:57.657469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-02T23:31:57.645397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-09-02T23:31:59.961673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-inlet-21077.herokuapp.com request_id=f5d6c0b9-b4e3-4cdb-927f-dcf1a103c0f7 fwd="67.162.53.201" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: This is the culprit here: `Unable to create index directory: /var/lucene/indexes for index babstr.model.Entry`. In your local lock `/var/lucene` and you will see that you will get something similar. I haven't "played" with Heroku, but if you are able to create that directory and the application has access to it, this error should vanish.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Thanks for quick response! I just checked it localy.. you are right,  directory /var/lucene/indexes is not created. Instead its creating babstr.model.Entry in the root of the project. What is odd that search is working fine

Comment: In my application.properties i have
 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem

and 

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /var/lucene/indexes

right now its saving on my disc... how to specify it right for heroku?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `/tmp` should be available in (almost) every UN*X system. Try changing the location to `/tmp` and take it from there. Another thing is, if you deploy this in several servers/instances, the indexes will get  created for each and eventually will be out-of-sync super-easy, so I think storing them in a database (Couchbase or MongoDB) will make more sense.

Comment: Man, you were right! after adding dot before path its start saving in the root directory: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase=./var/lucene/indexes`. Now its works fine on heroku!!!
Make your first comment as an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Nah, that's fine! You should place the answer and tell the steps you did to solve the problem, so anyone that faces the same problem can scroll right away to the solution. I only gave you a few pointers...that's it! See ya!

Answer (score 2):

@ɐuıɥɔɐɯ pointed me to the solution. For Spring boot application with hibernate search to work properly on Heroku, path for storing indexes need to be pointing to the root folder, NOT outside of it. 
In my case `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase=./var/lucene/indexes`
works fine.